# How to pull non-debuggable app user data on a non-rooted device (with a broken screen!)

Tags: adb, root-access, backup

I recently broke my Pixel 3a's screen and I've bought a replacement. Almost everything's ported over, except for some key app data that I want if at all possible. The Google backup didn't work, ADB backup creates 0 byte files.

I have access to the phone via USB Debugging. It's running Android 12. I think I'll need to root it, but while accounting for 1. the broken screen meaning I can only tell what I'm doing while USB debugging's working; and 2. that I don't want to trigger a factory reset during the root process.

Any thoughts? Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: You cannot get that app data without root access. What app is that? If USB Debugging is working you may get `scrcpy` working, in which case you can mirror your device's screen on your PC and interact with it. Which also means you can open the app and export/backup the data if your app offers such setting. Plus, depending upon the data you may be able to copy-paste it elsewhere. It would be tedious but that's all you can do anyway. Rooting process would factory reset the device. Don't follow it.

Comment: I have got scrcpy working, the app doesn't have any export/backup settings. I checked the phone's data folder and I can't access it publicly. I've got no way of accessing it without rooting the device. Could a soft root potentially work?

Comment: By soft root I suppose you mean using those rooting apps out there. No, they don't work. They rely on vulnerabilities in your device. You may try them just for the sake of trying.

Comment: How would I go about that with a broken screen? I wouldn't be able to use scrcpy while setting it up, right?